# The badges required for moderation are now mechanically enforced

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

On the [elections page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), it still says that the badge requirements are not mechanically enforced. This isn't true anymore, as a quick test proves. Can the text on the elections page be fixed?

Comment: @Shog9 Wait - is that "status completed - they are now no longer mechanically enforced" or "status completed - the badges are now mechanically enforced"

Comment: @Adam: the easy one, that involves deleting a bit of text from the election post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed now, as mentioned in the comments. Thanks!